# What is the best algorithm to turn an XML file into a key-value structure?

Tags: xml, serialization, xml-parsing, key-value

I had XML files like this:

```
<root>
    <key0>value</key0>
    <key1>value</key1>
    <key2>value</key2>
</root>
```

It's easy to turn such file into key-value structure. Let's showcase the result in Python dict, for example:

```
{'key0': 'value', 'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value'}
```

Now they added nested elements:

```
<root>
    <key0>value</key0>
    <key1>value</key1>
    <key2>value</key2>
    <key3>
        <sth0>value</sth0>
        <sth1>value</sth1>
    </key3>
</root>
```

Still easy:

```
{'key0': 'value', 'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value', 'key3/sth0': 'value', 'key3/sth1': 'value'}
```

I think you got the point. Now what about this?

```
<root>
    <key0>value</key0>
    <key1>value</key1>
    <key1>
         <inner>value</inner>
    </key1>
    <key2>value</key2>
    <key3>
        <sth0>value</sth0>
        <sth1>value</sth1>
    </key3>
    <key3>
        <sth0>different value</sth0>
        <sth1>different value</sth1>
    </key3>
    <key3>
        <sth0>blah blah</sth0>
        <sth1>blah blah</sth1>
    </key3>
</root>
```

Of course, I could come up with something after a while of thinking, but something tells me I would meet more and more difficulties. So the question is: Is there an complex algorithm to 'serialize' values in similarly simple XML file into key-value form? It has to be deterministically serializable and unserializable and no values can be lost. Order of elements doesn't matter (Python dict in examples is not a random choice, it's really what I'm trying to get).

I know XMLs can be very complex (namespaces, attributes, whatever), but this is not the case. The only problem I need to properly resolve is nested values as presented and related multiplicity of the same keys.

Comment: Why not use the XML as data, and use XPath to query the data? There are many pre-built libraries that implement this already. This one http://lxml.de even has 'objectify' too, which sounds close to what you want. I wouldn't name the sub elements like you have. I would make elements that have sub elements into collections.

Comment: I know turning these XMLs into 'objects' or 'documents' would be the best, but I can't do that right now. It's because I have a lot of legacy code working exclusively with key-value structures. I'd have to rewrite the whole ecosystem, which is not possible now. I need a middle step.

Comment: You could append something unique to the end of each name. Like <Key0> becomes Key0_unique , where unique is a ascending number or guid.

Comment: If you write it as an answer, I'd be able to accept it. I used algorithm similar to that and I think it is the best approach for the problem I presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append something unique to the end of each name. Like  becomes Key0_unique , where unique is a ascending number or guid.

(Although if your 'ecosystem' is big now and growing, I would consider sorting this out now rather than later.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best for you to use some sortf of xml-parser. I had similar issues and triend writing my xml parser for that, but as it turns out- it is not trivial and can change quite a bit. I could not recommend the following article more explaining the problem and common aproaches:

http://elegantcode.com/2010/08/07/dont-parse-that-xml/

If you can define a schema for that, you can use jaxb- nice and easy!

Comment: I have no problem with parsing the XML using common parsers or my own parser (I actually wrote a few of them). I have a problem with inventing an algorithm to serialize nested XML structure into key-value structure. See my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672801/what-is-the-best-algorithm-to-turn-an-xml-file-into-a-key-value-structure/12672837#comment17126711_12672801